# transform that is invariant under rotation

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

We know that the magnitude of the Fourier transform (resp. Mellin transform) of a shifted (resp. scaled) function is identical to the magnitude of the original function. I wonder if there is a transform that has some properties being invariant under rotation. Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in functions defined on $\mathbb R^2$ or on $\mathbb R^n$ for general $n$?

Comment: @user79365 $\mathbb{R}^2$ is good enough, but $\mathbb{R}^n$ is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Log-polar transformation converts rotations and dilations into translations, which are invariant under Fourier tranforms.